# Is working except it isnt opening my camera to get my face cords

Tags: python

```
import cv2
import mediapipe as mp
import pyautogui as py
cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

face_mesh = mp.solutions.face_mesh.FaceMesh(refine_landmarks=True)
while True:
    _, frame = cam.read()
    frame = cv2.flip(frame, 1)
    '''frameRGB = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)'''
    output = face_mesh.process(frameRGB)
    face_landmark = output.multi_face_landmarks
    frame_w, frame_h, _ = frame.shape
    '''if face_landmark:
        landmarks = face_landmark[0].landmark
        for landmark in enumerate(landmarks[474:478]):
            x = int(landmark.x * frame_w)
            y = int(landmark.y * frame_h)
            cv2.circle(frame, (x, y), 3, (0, 255, 0))
            if id == 1:
                py.moveTo(x, y)'''

            print(x, y)
    cv2.imshow('Lazy mouse', frame)
    cv2.waitKey(1)
```

it's printing where my head is for x, y, isnt showing me a camera with my face I believe it has to do with the frame or with the RGB I tried debugging but no luck, highlighted where I believe are the problems

Comment: which line is it giving error?

Comment: Is landmark of type tuple?

Comment: Your indentation is clearly wrong; please [edit] to fix it. On the desktop version of this site, you can get code marked up for you by pasting your code, selecting the pasted block, and typing ctrl-K.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`enumerate()` is a Python built-in function that returns a sequence of tuples.

Instead of

```
for landmark in enumerate(landmarks[474:478]):  # wrong
```

you should use

```
for landmark in landmarks[474:478]:
```

or

```
for (index, landmark) in enumerate(landmarks[474:478]):
```

`index` is the index into the sublist/slice, so you will get indices `0,1,2,3`

Comment: The parentheses in `for (index, landmark)` are superfluous.

Comment: sure, but they help newbies understand there's a tuple. unless you can show me style guidelines forbidding it, I will keep this. feel free to close. I did vote to. the first three commenters should have spotted this.

Comment: I already voted to close. Just commenting; I would have edited if I objected strongly to the parentheses. You might consider deleting this, as answers on closed (or close-worthy) questions tend to make it harder to delete them, especially if they are accepted or receive upvotes.